# Can you please add other folders back to sync options back to Ubuntu One in Windows?

Tags: ubuntu-one

Upgraded from the beta client to release 2 and now find that my old folders on my d: drive can no longer be added, only folders under my c:/docs and settings/user. I have a separate drive for data and this is where my documents resides.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about Ubuntu One on Windows.

You could try to create a Juction (a NTFS symbolic link) inside your User folder, that point to folder in D:. Here you can download the Junction utility:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768

I have not tried it, but may work.

Comment: Thanks. I have come up with a few work around,s, but I really liked the way the beta worked and was hoping it would not change as drastically.